# Keypad not working very often

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s, keyboard, text-input

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S i9003
Android: 2.3.6 (Gingerbread)

All of a sudden, the keypad stops working and after sometime it works just fine. When I try to type, I get the tapping sound. Letters pop-up, but nothing gets typed. Voice input also doesn't work at same time. Copy-paste, Whatsapp smiley, and Dialer number pad works.

I have tried clearing cache, but it doesn't make any difference. I have done factory reset many times, but the problem persists. This is the [trace](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ddj_uX6VLqRj9ZUohQvTX6ccHyuQQ6zwYqhIsbf0PPw/edit?usp=sharing) using CatLog at the point keypad doesn't work.